# Spawning player at a certain point after a new scene was loaded

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, scene

I have a Game Manager with a DontDestroyOnLoad function on it, before loading a scene I'm passing the variables needed to reset players position to a certain position. This is what my code looks like;

```
public IEnumerator LoadingNextLevel(int levelToLoad, string spawnPoint)
{
    pState.movingToNextLevel = true;
    fadeToBlack.SetTrigger("FadeOut");

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
    SceneManager.LoadScene(levelToLoad);
    fadeToBlack.SetTrigger("FadeIn");
    pState.movingToNextLevel = false;
    if (spawnPoint == "Red")
    {
        player.transform.position = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Red").transform.position;
    }
    else if (spawnPoint == "Blue")
    {
        player.transform.position = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Blue").transform.position;
    }
}
```

This doesn't give me any error, nor it does the job. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to update reference on player game object after loading new scene

Comment: @StrangerintheQ it should be updating in Awake with FindGameObjectWithTag

Comment: @StrangerintheQ oh I see what you are talking about.. Ok I've tried to find the game object with tag instead of using player, I think that it should work but it still doesn't.

Comment: you are trying to find the spawn points before they are loaded into the next scene. I would first load the new scene then check for the positions to start

Comment: @JustinMarkwell: I think this could be expanded into an upvote-worthy answer. :)

Comment: @JustinMarkwell he's not using LoadSceneAsync, so I believe it will finish loading before that call returns no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few different ways to handle but being this is in your persisting gamemanager code you can just add the async operation and first make sure the level is loaded. then you can find and set the spawns then change the positions.

```
public IEnumerator LoadingNextLevel(int levelToLoad, string spawnPoint)
{
    pState.movingToNextLevel = true;
    fadeToBlack.SetTrigger("FadeOut");

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
    AsyncOperation asyncLoad = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(levelToLoad);
    fadeToBlack.SetTrigger("FadeIn");
    pState.movingToNextLevel = false;
    // Wait until the asynchronous scene fully loads
    while (!asyncLoad.isDone)
    {
        yield return null;
    }
    if (spawnPoint == "Red")
    {
        player.transform.position = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Red").transform.position;
    }
    else if (spawnPoint == "Blue")
    {
        player.transform.position = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Blue").transform.position;
    }
}
```